# Order by a column in child table without fetching data from the child table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a cursor in which I retrieve data to execute a FOR loop. In the select statement of the cursor I want to order by a column which is in the child table, However I don't want to fetch data from the child table.

I tried by using a join but the data from the child table is also fetched to the cursor. I totally agree that it makes sense to have the data to execute the order by. I'm not sure whether this is feasible but really looking forward for a solution.

Example of my scenario.

```
CURSOR get_items_cursor_(rev_code_ IN VARCHAR2) IS
      SELECT *
      FROM   items_table
      WHERE  code = rev_code_ ;
```

Above is the simple cursor which is used in my FOR loop.

[image]

The table above shows sample data from the items_table

I want to order these data from is_original column from the child table part_items_table

[image: Sample data from Child table]

The above image shows data from the child table.

In the Cursor above I want to join the data using the item_id column and order by the is_original TRUE ones first. However I don't want to fetch data from the child table to the CURSOR.

I have tried the following

```
SELECT * FROM 
item_table item
INNER JOIN item_part_table item_part ON item.item_id =item_part.item_id
ORDER BY item_part.is_original DESC
```

The above select statement displays data from child table as well. Logically speaking the join should display data from child table, but in my scenario i just want to sort the above table using the child tables column.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT item.* FROM ...`

Comment: Is it possible scenario to have repeating ITEM_ID in ITEM_PART_TABLE where one value of IS_ORIGINAL = TRUE and other value where IS_ORIGINAL = FALSE? If Yes - which value of ITEM_TABLE you expect to see?

Comment: Only select the columns you need.  That is *always* true when using a cursor -- although it is questionable whether you actually need a cursor for the logic you want to implement.

Comment: @gogocho There can be repeated item_id in item_part_table with one is_original true, and the other false. I want to display both but i want to select the record with true first.

Comment: @HarryManoharan - So If you have two values for IS_ORIGINAL in PART_ITEMS_TABLE for ITEM_ID you want to display one and the same values for ITEM_ID, REV_CODE, ASSM_CODE, SLOT_CODE,ITEM_CODE from ITEM_TABLE twice in your result? But ordered by some column in child table. If we have three times ITEM_ID in PART_ITEMS_TABLE? Same result three times is expected?

Comment: Actually no, though the child table has two values, since it has a TRUE for is_original. i want to show that parent record first before the other parents which doesn't have a TRUE for is_original in the child table, not twice.

Answer (score 0):

you can join but select only columns you want like below:

so I'm just selecting only item_table columns , the only problem is you  are going to have duplicate and you can't use `distinct` because of the order that is not in the select list and that's why it gives you error

```
SELECT DISTINCT item.* 
FROM 
   item_table item
INNER JOIN item_part_table item_part 
   ON item.item_id =item_part.item_id
ORDER BY 
   item_part.is_original DESC
```

Comment: I get an error "ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression" when i execute your above query .

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `*` from select clause and use`item.*` and `item_part.is_original` as follows:

```
SELECT item.*, item_part.is_original FROM 
item_table item
INNER JOIN item_part_table item_part ON item.item_id =item_part.item_id
ORDER BY item_part.is_original DESC
```

Comment: But this way selects records from the item_part_table as well which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments please try this piece of code:

```
select item_id, rev_code, assm_code,slot_code, item_code
from
    (
        select
            c.*,
            row_number() over (partition by c.item_id order by p.is_original desc) as r_num,
            decode(p.is_original, 'TRUE', 1, 2) as ord_num
        from
            item_table c join part_items p on (p.item_id = c.item_id)
    )
where r_num = 1
order by ord_num;
```

Thanks.